# nopCommerce Authentication using Identity Server4 Implementation Issue

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce 4.40.3 and Identity Server 4. I am trying to integrate Identity Server authentication with NopCommerce. I have followed the existing ExternalAuth.Facebook project approach and created the plugin. I am able to install and configure the plugin successfully. I am able to show the "Identity Server Authentication" button and when I click it is redirecting to Identity Server Login Page and I am able to authenticate to Identity Server with out any issues. I can able to see the claims and I can see the success message in the identity server console. But NopCommerce site still shows not logged in and when I try to access different pages in NopCommerce, It is redirecting me to login page.

After login, I am able to see the Identity Server cookies like "idsrv" and "idsrv.session". When I logout from Identity Server, I can see both cookies are cleared out.

My question is, how can I set successful login to NopCommerce site.  Here's my implementation code. I don't know what I have missed in the configuration or in the implementation. Please help me.

**Identity Server Client Configuration:**

```
            new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "MiniApple.App.NopCommerce",
                    ClientId = "MiniApple.App.NopCommerce",
                    AllowedGrantTypes =GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>{ "https://localhost:44369/signin-oidc" },  //Client Application Address
                    RequirePkce = false,
                    RequireConsent = true,                    
                    AllowedScopes = {
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                       "MiniApple.API.Employee",
                       "roles"},
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Sha512()) },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "https://localhost:44369/signout-callback-oidc" }
                },
```

**NopCommerce Authentication Registration:**

```
 public class IdentityServerAuthenticationRegistrar : IExternalAuthenticationRegistrar
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">Authentication builder</param>
        public void Configure(AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        {            
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
                var settings = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IdentityServerExternalAuthSettings>();
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = settings.Authority;
                options.ClientId = settings.ClientKeyIdentifier;
                options.ResponseType = settings.ResponseType;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add(settings.Scope);
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });           
        }
    }
```

**Identity Server Console Output:**

```
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Token request validation success, {
        "ClientId": "MiniApple.App.NopCommerce",
        "ClientName": "MiniApple.App.NopCommerce",
        "GrantType": "authorization_code",
        "AuthorizationCode": "****F988",
        "RefreshToken": "********",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "MiniApple.App.NopCommerce",
          "client_secret": "***REDACTED***",
          "code": "18978F1D183EDFA3E3F5918B85F43DDFEAFE74D49E207E2449F59A9490BFF988",
          "grant_type": "authorization_code",
          "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44369/signin-oidc"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint for /connect/userinfo
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator[0]
      Profile service returned the following claim types: given_name family_name role
```

After successful login with identity server, it is redirecting to https://localhost:44369/signin-oidc and I am getting 404 error.

The issue is similar to the below
[question]: https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/60547/problems-making-custom-externalauth-plugin-for-openidconnect-to-auth0

Comment: I am able to fix the redirection issue after successful login from Identity Server. Still I do not know how to enable successful login into NopCommerce. Any direction or help really appreciated.                                                                                                         `

Answer (score 0):

Once I have changed the code as below, the authentication is works fine.

```
public void Configure(AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
                //Set Open Id Parameters
                var settings = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IdentityServerExternalAuthSettings>();
                options.Authority = settings.Authority;
                options.ClientId = settings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = settings.ResponseType;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add(settings.Scope);
                options.Scope.Add("roles");                
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                //options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {                   
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        var errorUrl = context.Properties.GetString(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.ErrorCallback);
                        context.Response.Redirect(errorUrl);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```